# Python script to parse text, create multiple files based on values in first column, and sort based on matching

Tags: python

As mentioned above, I'm having some trouble trying to create a script that will:

1. read and parse my tab-seperated file
2. create individual txt files named after the 20-ish, unique values in the first column
3. sort and collect all the lines with the same, unique first column value and write those into the respective text file.

I have so far been able to parse the original file and create empty files for each unique value in the original file.. but then I'm stuck.

```
file = open("path_to_document", 'rt')

Uniquelist = []

i = 0

for line in  file:

    parsedLine = line.strip().split('\t')
    val = parsedLine[0]
    if val not in Uniquelist:
        Uniquelist.append(val)
    for i in Uniquelist:
        outputfile = open('%s.txt' % i, 'a')
```

That's what I have so far, and it works, but it is completely missing the third part. I'm not sure of the logic or syntax needed to make it work

Comment: Writing to a file is documented well in many other places.  I suspect that all you *really* need is a reference to the `groupby` function in either NumPy or Pandas.  Either of those packages will handle your data set better than a simple list.  Is that enough to set you on the right path?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in the first column in a dictionary instead of a list. When you loop over the lines in the file, check if that value is already in the dictionary (if value *in* dict), if it isn't, create a new entry with the first value as key and the rest of the values (parsedLine[1:]) as the value. If it is, just add the rest of the values to that entry.
Then you can save that dict as a text file (or, if you can, json would make it even easier).

And yes there may be other libraries that will do exactly what you want, but for something so simple, I don't see the need to add external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


# read from the `tsv` file:
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.tsv', sep='\t')

# group-by unique values in the first column:
gb = df.groupby(0)

# iterate over the unique values in the first column and write the cross-section data to a file with the corresponding name
for value, df_ in gb:
    df_.to_csv(
        'value_{}.csv'.format(value), 
        index=False
    )
```